# Confusion with ASP.NET MVC one-to-many and many-to-many relationships and scaffolding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity, repository-pattern

As the title suggests, Im really struggling with this. I understand that the scaffolding feature doesn't fully support these relationships out of the box but I just cant seem to get a fairly common scenario to work. I am using code first with repository pattern. Some code...

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal PricePerUnit { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int QuantityPerCarton { get; set; }
    public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> CategoryList { get; set; }

}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UrlName { get; set; }
    public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

So I want a many-to-many relationship between the two objects. First problem. As soon as I add the virtual collections I get the 'the model backing the 'Context' context has changed since the database was created'. This happens even after I perform migrations etc.

Secondly I dont quite understand (once this works), how to get these lists into the view. There doesnt seem to be a perfect go-to resource to explain this. Can anyone shed some more concrete light on this or an end-to-end sample?

This should be simple!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've used EF for the scenario you mention without problems in the past. You can find a very good tutorial about loading related resources with EF in the official [ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). You might also find some more information there on your first problem which looks Migrations related.

Comment: Thanks, Ive definitely used this already but find that it doesnt really cover many-to-many well, if at all.

Looking at their example, I dont understand how the Enrollments class is even used, and with the migration no database table is produced. So where is the relationship held? I have seen other examples where this is managed at the context onModelCreating but the samples seem old and wonder if there are better/newer ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

OK resolved it. The asp.net site did help. My mistake was that I wasnt doing the migration on the right layer of the application so my many-to-many table was never being created. Doh!